# How to count the number of strokes of Chinese characters in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need to count the number of strokes of Chinese characters (UTF-8) in iOS, how to do that ?

Is there any built-in method to do the task ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various stroke-related properties defined in the [Unihan](http://unicode.org/charts/unihan.html) database, since different countries/languages may have diverging stroke counts.

I suggest extracting the [kTotalStrokes](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/) property value for each character from Unihan for lookup in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is quite similar to what I am looking for. One question: how to implement the Unihand database in Objective-C for offline use ?